# Setting Drawable to imageView

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, drawable

I am currently trying to retrieve icons of a package and set it into a imageView with this code. ai is a Drawable.

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageName);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)ai).getBitmap();

    Log.i("Icons Drawable", ai.toString());
    Log.i("Icons Bitmap", bitmap.toString());

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Logcat output:

```
    11-06 11:10:22.785: I/Icons Drawable(20017): android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@416184f0
    11-06 11:10:22.785: I/Icons Bitmap(20017): android.graphics.Bitmap@41618488

11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1973)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1999)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4513)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:974)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:741)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at com.analyze.project.MalwareAlertDialog.onCreate(MalwareAlertDialog.java:98)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
11-06 11:10:22.790: E/AndroidRuntime(20017):    ... 11 more
```

Even if i try to set the Drawable to the imageView directly it doesn't work

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ai);
```

Comment: I suspect `imageView` is `null`. What is line 98, and how is `imageView` defined?

Comment: Line 98 is `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`. `imageView` is defined as         `imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo info=pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
imageView.setImageDrawable(info.loadIcon(pm));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use input stream
this is an example

```
InputStream floorIs = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.floor_texture);

InputStream wallIs =context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall_mayu_texture);

InputStream wallIs2 = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall_buzoo_texture);

InputStream wallIs3 = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall_niko_texture);

InputStream wallWindowIs =context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.wall_window_texture);

InputStream ceilingIs = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ceiling_texture);

Bitmap bitmaps[] = new Bitmap[6];
bitmaps[0] = null;
bitmaps[1] = null;
bitmaps[2] = null;
bitmaps[3] = null;
bitmaps[4] = null;
bitmaps[5] = null;
            try{
                bitmaps[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(floorIs);
                bitmaps[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(wallIs);
                bitmaps[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(wallWindowIs);
                bitmaps[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ceilingIs);
                bitmaps[4] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(wallIs2);
                bitmaps[5] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(wallIs3);
            }
            finally{
                try{
                    floorIs.close();
                    floorIs = null;
                    wallIs.close();
                    wallIs = null;
                    wallIs2.close();
                    wallIs2 = null;
                    wallIs3.close();
                    wallIs3 = null;
                    wallWindowIs.close();
                    wallWindowIs = null;
                    ceilingIs.close();
                    ceilingIs = null;
                }
                catch(IOException e){}
            }
```

after this try to load the bitmap to the imageview you defined before using

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit of a naive question, but since this is happening in your onCreate() callback, and you're getting a null pointer exception for that ImageView, did you forget to call setContentView to inflate your layout?  It's possible that your layout was never created, which means that the View you're trying to draw to also doesn't exist.

Comment: if i don't set the ImageView it will display the custom alert dialog.